# How many arrangements are possible for the given input array so that all of them will give same output in first pass of quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given input array as  60,80,15,95,7,12,35,90,55 , and condition as chosing first element as pivot ,Now how many arrangements are possible for the given input so that the output for the first pass of quicksort gives the same result ?

I tried with some permutations and for each permutation I got the same output in the first pass but I couldn't get the logic behind this , so I changed the input array and then tried and I found that it gave different results so on what factor does this effect depend that the input array gives same result for some particular permutation of given input array ,please generalize this terminology .

Comment: I'm sure that if you exchange 80 and 95 or 15 and 7 the order after the first pass will be different. Just follow the algorithm and see what it does.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the partition scheme being used, such as Lomuto type versus Hoare type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to keep the same output after the first pass, what we must *not* do is change the order of any elements that will appear on the same side of the pivot -- that is, any pair of elements that are both `<= 60`, or both `> 60`.  Doing that would change the order that they appear in the final output.  It's OK to change the order of a pair of elements if one is `<= 60` and the other is `> 60`.

So for each category (`<= 60` and `> 60`) we need to choose the correct order for its elements beforehand, and not violate this order.  This means that what we are essentially doing is merging two lists -- one containing all items `<= 60` in the order that we want them to appear, and the other containing all items `> 60` in the order that we want them to appear.  That is, if we take some number of elements, in order, from one of the lists, and then some number of elements, in order, from the other, and repeat this until both input lists are empty, then the sequence of elements taken will generate the desired final order after 1 quicksort pass.

So, how many ways can this be done?  There are 5 numbers `<= 60`: 15, 7, 12, 35, 55, and 3 numbers `> 60`: 80, 95, 90.  We can describe the sequence of choices involved in generating a merged sequence as a sequence of 0s and 1s, with 0 meaning "take the next element from the `<= 60` list" and 1 meaning "take the next element from the `> 60` list".  Then what we want to know is the number of different sequences of 0s and 1s that contain exactly 5 0s and 3 1s -- or equivalently, the number of ways of choosing 3 out of 5+3=8 positions in a sequence of 0s to turn into 1s.  That is `8 choose 3`, or `8!/3!5! = 56`.  This counts every possible valid merge exactly once, so there are 56 ways of ordering the last 8 elements of 60, 80, 15, 95, 7, 12, 35, 90, 55 to produce a particular output sequence after 1 pass of quicksort.

Comment: I couldn't get the last part of the logic where you applied 8C3 , why are we chosing only 3 1's , why not chosing 5 0's although result would be same but still I couldn't follow the logic of merging two lists where each list maintains its order ,please clarify a bit more

Answer (score 1):

First let me tell you what happens in Quick sort after first pass and first element taken as pivot is, the pivot element will be move to its exact position i.e. all the elements less than the pivot will be left to it and greater to it will be right of it.Whatever is less to it will be relatively in same relative position (i.e. 15,7,12 are less than 60 will be in same relative order means 7 is after 15 and before 12) as it was before except the one which will be replaced by the pivot.

In Your example  60,80,15,95,7,12,35,90,55 , once you will take 60 as pivot then all the element less than 60 should be at the same relative position as it is in the above sequence. So get all those permutation,we need to maintain below conditions

1. 60 will be the first as it will be chosen as pivot element.
2. From remaining 8 element, there are 5 elements less than 60 (i.e 5,7,12,35,55). We will maintain there relative position.So we will choose 5 position from 8 and we will put these 5 element in the same order and other 3 elements ( i.e 80,95,90) will be placed remaining vacant places.

So this complete problem, reduce into choosing 5 places( number of element less than pivot) form the 8 places (number of total numbers except pivot). So this will be 8C5 or 8C3.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say, the elements > 60 are A, B & C and elements <= 60 are a, b, c, d & e. And after 1st pass of partition algorithm, we always want the sequence -
a , b , c , d , e , 60 , A , B , C

Now, if we select any 3 positions (P1, P2, P3) in the input array for placing elements > 60, such as -

60 , _ , P1, _ , P2 , _ , _ , P3 , _

then, after 1st pass of partition, we'll get a sequence in which P1, P2 & P3 are to the right of 60, but in any order. Lets say, we got -

_ , _ , _ , _ , _ , 60 , P3 , P1 , P2

Comparing with the required output sequence, we can say that -

placing A at P3,

placing B at P1,

placing C at P2

in the input array, that is,

60 , _ , B , _ , C , _ , _ , A , _

gives the required output sequence.

With the above analysis, we can say that for any 3 positions selected for elements > 60, we can always get the required output sequence by backtracking the positions.
Now, in how many ways can we select any 3 positions for elements > 60 ?
The answer is 8C3 (no. of ways of selecting any 3 items out of 8 items; in our case, item refers to position) = 56.

NOTE - In the positions left vacant by elements > 60, we can put elements <= 60 in the order -

b c, d, e, a

so that at the last step of partition, 60 is swapped by 'a' to give the required output sequence -

a, b, c, d, e